# Error using brownie on Vscode while running scripts

Tags: solidity, npm-scripts, brownie

I get the following ERROR when I try to run scripts with brownie, using the following PowerShell command;

```
brownie run scripts/simple_collectible/deploy_simple
```

I have look all over stacked and other pages for info on this and I can't seem to find much, I would really like to carry on with my project but I am stuck at this point. any hekp would be wonderful.

Cheers!

INFO MESSAGE:

PS C:\Users\charl\OneDrive\Desktop\NFT Development\NFT-mix-main> brownie run scripts/simple_collectible/deploy_simple
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

NftMixMainProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
File "C:\Users\charl.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie_cli_*main*_.py", line 64, in main
importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
File "C:\Users\charl.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie_cli\run.py", line 46, in main
path, _ = _get_path(args[""])
File "C:\Users\charl.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 130, in _get_path
raise FileNotFoundError(f"Cannot find {path_str}")
FileNotFoundError: Cannot find scripts/simple_collectible/deploy_simple
Terminating local RPC client...

I have the following packages installed:

- ganache-cli
- pip
- pipx
- Brownie (installed through pipx, and initialized)
- I have run the brownie command to make sure the install is good.
- I have install Python Venv
- I have tried uninstalling all packaged and reinstalling
- I have done the same with my VScode and Vsbuildtools
- I have done the same with Python itself (reinstalled from the website)

The code snippet I have for my Script that I am trying to run is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os

from brownie import SimpleCollectible, accounts, config, network


def main():
    dev = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
    print(network.show_active())
    publish_source = True if os.getenv("ETHERSCAN_TOKEN") else False
    SimpleCollectible.deploy({"from": dev}, publish_source=publish_source)
```

And finally for your reference I have my brownie-config.yaml contents here:

```
# exclude SafeMath when calculating test coverage
# https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.3/config.html#exclude_paths
reports:
  exclude_contracts:
    - SafeMath
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
# automatically fetch contract sources from Etherscan
autofetch_sources: True
dotenv: .env
# set a custom mnemonic for the development network
networks:
  default: development
  kovan:
    vrf_coordinator: '0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9'
    link_token: '0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088'
    keyhash: '0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4'
    fee: 100000000000000000
    oracle: '0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e'
    jobId: '29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8'
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331'
  rinkeby:
    vrf_coordinator: '0xb3dCcb4Cf7a26f6cf6B120Cf5A73875B7BBc655B'
    link_token: '0x01be23585060835e02b77ef475b0cc51aa1e0709'
    keyhash: '0x2ed0feb3e7fd2022120aa84fab1945545a9f2ffc9076fd6156fa96eaff4c1311'
    fee: 100000000000000000
    oracle: '0x7AFe1118Ea78C1eae84ca8feE5C65Bc76CcF879e'
    jobId: '6d1bfe27e7034b1d87b5270556b17277'
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e'
  mumbai:
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0x0715A7794a1dc8e42615F059dD6e406A6594651A'
  binance:
    # link_token: ??
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0x9ef1B8c0E4F7dc8bF5719Ea496883DC6401d5b2e'
  binance-fork:
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0x9ef1B8c0E4F7dc8bF5719Ea496883DC6401d5b2e'
  mainnet-fork:
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419'
  matic-fork:
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0xF9680D99D6C9589e2a93a78A04A279e509205945'
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
  from_mnemonic: ${MNEMONIC}
  # You'd have to change the accounts.add to accounts.from_mnemonic to use from_mnemonic
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `scripts/simple_collectible/deploy_simple` -> `scripts/simple_collectible/deploy_simple.py`

Comment: Hi Patrick Cheers for the Answer, I've tried that one and got another error. See below:              `  "C:\Users\charl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 130, in _get_path    
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"Cannot find {path_str}")
FileNotFoundError: Cannot find scripts/simple_collectible/deploy_simple.py `

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: Cannot find scripts/simple_collectible/deploy_simple.py` This means it can't find that file. Please make sure your `deploy_simple.py` is in the correct location.